# How to convert a page generated from server to a big component in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a page generated from server side and I want to use angular2 to operate its elements how can i do that?
Similar like Vue:
I can use initialize the whole page by giving its element id and i can operate the elements i want.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

Comment: IHave you had a look at the [5 minutes quickstart from Angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)? It is a bit difficult to understand what you want to do. You could use a Component with @Input() decorators and create it when you get data from your service? Or create a component that loads data from a service and then bind the data to your html-template?

Comment: yes, i did. I know the way you are talking about, it generate template in client side. However my project pages are rendered from server side, how can i operate the elements in Angular? I don't want to use getElementById to operate it either.

Comment: Ok. Then I am not sure. Maybe [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io) is something you would want to have a look at?

Comment: Angular Universal is not what i am looking for. It renders angular component from server side. We have already have our solution on server side. That's not gonna change. Maybe VUE is more suitable for this case. Thanks all the same